# my custom collectionView is choppy when scrolling

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

please i have create custom collectionView when load the images from document directory to collectionView Cell i can't scrolling fast my custom collectionView is choppy when scrolling i don't know why?
please can anyone tell me what am doing on this problem

the following my code :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AlbumImagesCollectionViewCell


    if dictionaryOfSelectItem.count > 0 {
        if dictionaryOfSelectItem[indexPath.row] == indexPath.row {
            cell.imageViewCheck.image = UIImage(named: "check.png")
        }else {
            cell.imageViewCheck.image = nil
        }

    }

        cell.imageViewCheck.image = nil
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if self.arrayOfImageUrl2.count > 0 && self.arrayOfImagesFromDocumentDirectory.count > 0 {
                cell.imageViewCell.image = self.ResizeImage(self.arrayOfImagesFromDocumentDirectory[indexPath.row], targetSize: CGSize(width: 140.0, height: 140.0))
                cell.imageUrlLabel.text = self.arrayOfImageUrl2[indexPath.row]
            }

        })
    }

    return cell

}
```

Thanks Advance

Comment: Do you prefetch the images? Did you try resizing the image outside of the cellForItemAtIndexPath? I think ResizeImage or fetching the image is taking up significant time.

Comment: yes i resize the images but if i get the image only from the cell us have no high quality and resolution and also am try to delete the resizing image also the still problem have in collectionView

Comment: Also what does self.arrayOfImagesFromDocumentDirectory[indexPath.row] holds? Does it fetch image from documentDirectory each and every time?

Comment: Try resizing the image in the global queue before setting it on the main queue. Anything that happens on the main queue will contribute to choppiness